# Repeat function in javascript

Tags: javascript, function

Could you please tell me how to make from this 4 functions just 1. Cause they all do one thing, with just one parameter changing all the time.
Also, I need to take the value of each time the function is running and put it into a new variable so I can after calculate it.

```
function getValue(age)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < document.getElementsByName('age').length; i++)
    {
        if (document.getElementsByName('age')[i].checked)
        {
            return document.getElementsByName('age')[i].value;
        }
    }
}


function getBmiValue()
{
    for (var i = 0; i < document.getElementsByName('bmi').length; i++)
    {
        if (document.getElementsByName('bmi')[i].checked)
        {
            return document.getElementsByName('bmi')[i].value;
        }
    }
}    

function getFamValue()
{
 for (var i = 0; i < document.getElementsByName('fam').length; i++)
 {
    if (document.getElementsByName('fam')[i].checked)
        {
            return document.getElementsByName('fam')[i].value;
        }
    }   
 }

function getDietValue()
{
 for (var i = 0; i < document.getElementsByName('diet').length; i++)
  {
      if (document.getElementsByName('diet')[i].checked)
       {
            return document.getElementsByName('diet')[i].value;
       }
    }     
}
```

Comment: Pass the element name as a parameter to your function. You'll need to have a basic understanding of the language syntax, so I'd recommend learning a bit more JavaScript before going too much further.

Answer (score 2):

```
function getValueByElementName(element_name)
{
 for (var i = 0; i < document.getElementsByName(element_name).length; i++)
 {
    if (document.getElementsByName(element_name)[i].checked)
        {
            return document.getElementsByName(element_name)[i].value;
        }
    }   
 }
```

Or a little bit optimization:

```
function getValueByElementName(element_name)
{
   var elements = document.getElementsByName(element_name);

   for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++)
   {
      if (elements[i].checked)
            return elements[i].value;
    }   
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function getValue(tagname)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < document.getElementsByName(tagname).length; i++)
    {
        if (document.getElementsByName(tagname)[i].checked)
        {
            return document.getElementsByName(tagname)[i].value;
        }
    }
}
```

Pass your element name as a variable in this function and call it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of what you can do:

```
function getValue(key) {

// get this once, not on each loop iteration  
var elem = document.getElementsByName(key);

  // cache the length too, so not to calculate it on each loop iteration
  for (var i = 0, len = elem.length; i < len; i++) {

    if (elem[i].checked) {
      return elem[i].value; 
      // this will exit the function when it finds the FIRST one. 
      // Is that what you want?
    }
  }
}

// you can call above function like this:
getValue('age');
getValue('bmi');
getValue('fam');
getValue('diet');
```